# Does Number.toFixed() use locale conventions?

Tags: javascript, localization

I am writing a JavaScript function that can perform decimal place manipulation on a string that was generated from a number using Number.toFixed().  Part of what I need to accomplish is to locate the location of the decimal point in the formatted string.  I have begun to wonder, however, whether the toFixed() function will use locale specific formatting (e.g. '.' versus ',' for the decimal point).  If that is the case, I can't merely search for the '.' character but may need to search for a comma or, perhaps, some other separator that is used in other locales.

In C++, I can use the numpunct locale facet to determine what character is used but I don't believe that there is any equivalent resource available in JavaScript.  My question then becomes whether toFixed() is going to honour locale conventions and, if so, is there any way to recognise what convention is used on the browser host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, i does not. Only `.toLocaleString()` respects decimal separator. Neither `Number('42,6')` will return proper value assuming locale have ',' as decimal separator.

Comment: Are you sure it is consistent behavior across all web browsers? Especially localized versions of Internet Explorer?

Comment: @Paweł Dyda, even IE8 is compliant

Answer (score 3):

```
// You can always ask-

Number.decimalChar= (function(){
    return (3/5).toLocaleString().charAt(1)
})()

alert(Number.decimalChar)
```

Comment: Not good enough unless you adapt it for thousands separators as well--try, for example, (1000.1).toLocaleString('fr').